# Defer Images(Not Lazy Loading) NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to lazy load images, but that doesn't load the images fast enough(nextJS and intersection observer). So, I've decided to defer my image loads for important images. In that way they should start loading as soon as the initial paint is done, but still not block the entire thread.

How can this be done in NextJS?

I've tried setting the image URL inside `useEffect`, but I'm not sure if it blocks the main thread. Does it?

Comment: Have you considered using the `loading="lazy"` attribute on the `<img>` element? Supported by [most major browsers, except Safari](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr).

Comment: @juliomalves that's thing, we need Safari support :(

Answer (score 1):

when you use `Next/Image`, by default it has Lazy.
You can change loading property to `eager`.

> When eager, load the image immediately.

[Next/Image lazy load](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loading)

Comment: I can't use `Next/Image` as there are some problems regarding positioning

Comment: also "immediately" is the opposite of what he asked, he wants to DEFER it